# How to overload operator "<<" to output integer values in one case and char values in another case?

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Vector& right_hand_side)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < right_hand_side.size; ++i)
    {
        // Printing array integers
        ostr << right_hand_side.array[i] << " ";
    }
    ostr << std::endl;
    return ostr;
}
```

> I have a custom vector class. It works well, but only with integer values. I want to expand its functionality and add char values. I need to achieve such a result that it will be possible to create vectors for both int and char. This overloaded operator displays only int values. How do I make it support char values?
> Here's the vector class header file

```
#pragma once
```

#include

```
class Vector {
public:
Vector(); // Default constructor
Vector(const Vector& rhs); // copy constructor
Vector(int elements, int value = 0);
Vector(const std::initializer_list<int>& list);

~Vector(); // destructor

void PushBack(int value); // Add an element to the end of the vector.
void PushBackChar(int value); // Add an element to the end of the
```

vector.

```
void PopBack(); // Deletes the element at the end of the vector.

bool Empty() const; // Tests if the vector container is empty.
int Size() const; // Returns the number of elements in the vector.
int Capacity() const; // Returns the number of elements that the vector could contain without allocating more storage.

bool operator==(const Vector& right_hand_side) const;
bool operator!=(const Vector& right_hand_side) const;

friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ostr, const Vector& rhs);

Vector& operator=(const Vector& rhs);

int& operator[](int index);
int& At(int index); // Returns a reference to the element at a specified location in the vector.
int& Front(); // Returns a reference to the first element in a vector.
int& Back(); // Returns a reference to the last element of the vector.

void Insert(int index, int value); // Inserts an element or many elements into the vector at a specified position.
void Erase(int index);  // Removes an element or a range of elements in a vector from specified positions.
void Clear(); // Erases the elements of the vector.
private:
int size;
int capacity;
int* array;
char* char_array;
};
```

Comment: You need to implement the vector class to support chars. How is vector implemented currently? And by the way, why are you doing this and not using std::vector?

Comment: The assignment was that I need to create my vector class from scratch without using the utilities of the standard vector class and the template feature of C++

Comment: Then we cannot help you if do not share any information of the Vector class

Comment: Haha. You're right) We were asked to reinvent the bicycle. Maybe it's good, maybe not, I don't know, but it's still an experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Vector` only stores `int`s, then you only have `int`s to output. I think your instructor is asking for you to have a `Vector_int` class that holds `int`s and a `Vector_char` class that holds `char`s, and basically identical implementations.

Aside: I'd recommend going through your existing implementation, and changing all uses of `int` that are indexes or sizes to `std::size_t`, so that when you copy your implementation for `char` you can do a replace-all in your text editor.

I hope the learning outcome of this exercise is "and this is why templates exist"